# android library unit testing gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

```
I have an android library project.
```

I can run the android tests in android studio.
I am not sure how to trigger the tests from the gradle file.
Tried few things but nothing helped. Folder structure is src/main and src/androidTest

Gradle file is below:-

```
   ...
    sourceSets {
    androidTest.setRoot('src/androidTest/java')
    androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/java']
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task for testing should include your flavor and build type.

Firstly, you can check available tasks using

```
gradle tasks --all
```

if it fails, check why

```
gradle tasks --stacktrace
```

In the output you'll see all the tasks, that are available.

I'm shure that you can run unit-tests, that are under /test folder.
I didn't find the task for running instrumentation tests that are under /androidTest.

If you created unit-tests under /androidTest, I'd recommend you to use
[Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) and move them to /test folder, it's pretty easy. After that you'll be able to run them with gradle.